# Can I refer to a subclass in another subclass?

Tags: python, excel, class

This is a somewhat general question.

**If I am creating a class with functions in it can i refer to another function in that class?**

For ex does this work:

```
class pythonExcelFunctions():

    def getSheetNumber(self, fileName, sheetName):

        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fileName, on_demand=True)

        for index, sheet in enumerate(workbook.sheet_names()):
            if sheet == sheetName:
                return index

    def createSheet(self, fileName, sheetName):


        rb = xlrd.open_workbook(fileName, formatting_info=True, on_demand=True)


        wb = xl_copy(rb)


        Sheet1 = wb.add_sheet(getSheetNumber(fileName, sheetName))


        wb.save(fileName)
```

Comment: You have the code ... Why not try it?  If it _doesn't_ work, can you point to where it's failing?

Comment: Note you are missing a parenthesis on the line in question

Comment: I don't think that subclass is what you meant here.

Comment: I don't know the difference between definition, class, superclass, subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, via that self variable. In this case, instead of `getSheetNumber(fileName, sheetName)` You'd want to do `self.getSheetNumber(fileName, sheetName)`. Self is basically the instance of the class, and you need to tell python which instance to call that function on.